# @Input not taking latest value after emitted from parent component

Tags: angular

I have parent component which emittes latest value and in child component it uses @Input wheire in it does not return latest value.

Basically it starts like this
in child component...

```
@Input() test;any;
```

We do bind this test into HTML and then  on click event of button we do something with input value 'test'

```
onClickButton() {

this.test='your request is in progress'
....does some function where in it passes call to parent componentt and there it retrives the latest data of test so I am expecting that this.test would replaced by latest data from parent component.

}
```

However, this is not the case here, it retains 'your request is in progress...'

I tried in child component like ngOnChanges(changes:simpleChanges)  and tried to assign currentValue to the this.test value; but things are not moving in right direction. everything process right even in parent component i tried printing latest value but in child it remains old value.

I also tried

```
this.ref.detectChanges();
this.ref.markforCheck();
```

but things are not helping me any ways to get updated value from Parent Component.

Parent.ts

this.test ="getting value from services and can see in debugger that value is coming"

Comment: Give your template file structure of parent where you use child-component..

Comment: `@Input()` only checks changes when reference of input-property is changed. If you simply changes values then reference of object is same and thus onChanges is not getting to work.. `this.obj = { ...this.obj }` this de-structuring syntax you have changed values and reference too.. now onChanges() is get to be fired..

Comment: please see update in main thread.

Comment: in my parent component, this.test="last value from services" , this I varified in the debugger itself.

Comment: even on when I hover the changes object i can see currentValue is the latest values I am expecting, however when it prints the value when i clicked on button this.test="your request is in progress", still I dont understand whats going wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

We  need to see your parent component.

With your current code, we don't see the moment where you override `test` variable into the parent component.

I made a StackBlitz [just here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lkjxys), is this what you need ?

Feel free to edit and send it back.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [StackBlitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cyl4pd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.html)

Your html of parent.html...

```
<button (click)="changeValue()">Change</button>
 <hr>
<app-child [test] ="test"></app-child>
```

Your .ts of parent.ts...

```
export class AppComponent  {
   test:any ={};
   changeValue(){
       this.test['data'] = 'loading data form server...'
       setTimeout(()=>{
           this.test['data'] = "Loaded..."
       },500)
   }
}
```

Your child.html is...

```
{{value |json}}
```

Your child.ts is...

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
   value:any;
   @Input('test') set testInput(value : any){
     this.value = value;
   }  
   constructor() { }
   ngOnInit() {
   } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gaurang, when I debug my code [ngOnChanges], it in currentValue it gives right value but it prints old value to html.

Comment: @user5769212 Welcome, if answer is helpful to you can upvote and accept it..

Comment: I have this issue, when I debug my code [ngOnChanges], it in currentValue it gives right value but it prints old value to html

Comment: can you share it on stackblitz ? rather you can use my setter approach of @Input() changes , then update latest value to property by yourself